Have to source file after terminal is open for function to work
I am trying to make a terminal prank that plays noise for every output that happens on the terminal:
exec > >(tee >(while true; do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    FREQ=$(echo "$line" | od -An -N2 -i | awk '{print ($1 % 1000) + 200}')
    sox -n -b 8 -c 1 -r 8000 -d synth 0.01 saw $FREQ tremolo 1000 2> /dev/null
  done
done)) 2>&1

It almost works really well. I have dropped it into the bashrc, however, this function does not work unless I have an already open terminal and then source it directly. How do I reformat this so that it will run just from being in the bashrc?
Thanks!

It works for me if I paste it into my ~/.bashrc. Are you sure your ~/.bashrc is being sourced? Are you by any chance testing this in a login shell with your ~/-profile not sourcing ~/.bashrc? Otherwise please post the contents of your ~/.bashrc

... or your terminal is configured to use a shell that is either not bash or does not source the rc file(s) ex. /bin/bash -norc?

As both @kos and @steeldriver mentioned, this works well on bash, however I am embarrassed to say that I was using zsh the whole time. However, if anyone is interested in making that work, here is the following:
alias ls='ls -C --color=always'
if [[ -o interactive ]]; then
  log_and_play() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      FREQ=$(echo "$line" | od -An -N2 -i | awk '{print ($1 % 1000) + 200}')
      sox -n -b 8 -c 1 -r 8000 -d synth 0.01 aw $FREQ tremolo 1000 2> /dev/null
    done
  }

  preexec() {
    exec > >(tee >(log_and_play)) 2>&1
  }

  precmd() {
    true
  }
fi


I don't want to send in an edit this heavy, so I'll mention what I think could be improved: 1. The ls alias and precmd function seem irrelevant here, so maybe they could be removed 2. [[ -o interactive ]] could be written in a more portable way as [[ $- == *i* ]] 3. No need to echo to od, just <<<"$line" od [...] 4. This will dirsrupt normal usage of the terminal. Try for example vim / nano. I mean, maybe it's meant to be part of the comedic effect? I don't know shrug
